# Tail recursion - Scala (any language else)

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

i have a question about Tail recursion. As i know Tail recursion is when the last recursive call from function will deliver the result of the function. But when i have a function like this

```
def func1(n: Int): Int = {
   if (n > 100) {
      n - 10
   }
   else {
      func1(func1(n + 11))
   }
}
```

would it be tail recursion ? For example

```
func1(100) = func1(func1(111)) = func1(101) = 91
```

so the last recursive call would be func1(101) and it should deliver the results so that would be tail recursion right? I'm a little confused. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's not tail-recursive. You could rewrite the code to look like this:

```
def func1(n: Int): Int = {
   if (n > 100) {
      n - 10
   }
   else {
      val f = func1(n + 11)
      func1(f)
   }
}
```

You can see that there is a call to func1 on line 6 that is not in the tail position.

Comment: thank you! but why is func1 on line 6 is not in the tail position ? if it calls the function again, shouldn't it also be in the tail position and calls to another function like the one in line 7 ?

Comment: This code is not tail-recursive. `val f = func1(n + 11)` - here you go deeper in a call stack.

Comment: ah i see why it's not. Because after it's done and returns the value the fuction still has to be called again with input as that value. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 4):

Any easy way to check would be to just try it.  the @tailrec annotation (import scala.annotation.tailrec) will give you a compile-time error if your method is not tail recursive.

This is not tail recursive though because you have a recursive call in a non-tail position.

You have two recursive calls in your function, one is in a tail position, it's the last call in the method, but the other is the input to that call, which isn't tail recursive because something comes after it, the next call.  It's not enough to have one recursive call in the tail position, every recursive call must be a tail call

Answer (score 0):

No, your example is not a case of tail recursion.

`func1(func1(n + 11))` is a case of non-linear recursion (particularly, nested recursion).

Tail recursion is a particular case of linear recursion that can be immediately converted into iteration (loop), which is why it is interesting, as it allows easy optimization.

In your case, the call to the inner function is not the last operation in the function (there is still pending the call to the outer function), thus, it is not tail recursion.

Comment: so a recursion must be a linear recursion first in order to be a tail recursion ?

Comment: yes, tail recursion is a particular case of linear recursion. In tail recursion, the recursive call is last, this implies that there is only one recursive call (which means linear recursion)

Answer (score 0):

Actually tail recursive method is a method which 'returns' a result itself  or next invocation. If you can rewrite your algorithm the following way - it can be tail recursive.

```
trait Recursive[R] {
  def oneIteration: Either[R, Recursive[R]]
}

object Recursive {
  def interpret[R](fn: Recursive[R]): R = {
    var res: Either[R, Recursive[R]] = Right(fn)
    while(res.isRight) {
      res = res.right.get.oneIteration
    }
    res.left.get
  }
}

object Factorial extends App {
  def factorial(acc: BigDecimal, n: Int): Recursive[BigDecimal] = new Recursive[BigDecimal] {
    override def oneIteration(): Either[BigDecimal, Recursive[BigDecimal]] = {
      if(n == 1 ){
        Left(acc)
      }
      else {
        Right(factorial(acc * n, n - 1))
      }
    }
  }

  val res = Recursive.interpret(factorial(1 , 5))
  println(res)
}
```

Comment: This code is cool.  But it uses `while` and uses a `var`.  Not sure it's relevant here.

Comment: It just shows how tail recursion works. No need to use it in production) I used `var` and `while` instead of `tailrec` to show how tail recursion can be emulated without language support.