# Separation of concerns

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to learn functional programming in scala with book [FPiS](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) in chapter 5 the author mentions:

> A major theme in functional programming is separation of concerns and
>   seperating program description from evaluation.

What does it mean? Could someone give an example?

Comment: I think *separation of concerns* is a major topic in any programming language. Based on what I have learned, it means that you should *subdivide a program into parts that each (aim to) solve a concern/problem*. The parts should be as independent from the other parts as possible.

Comment: What does `program description` mean?

Comment: a document describing what the program is supposed to do. For instance a program description can be "*a system where a person enters orders, and where an employee can mark which orders are completed*". Although usually it is of course more extensive.

Comment: If you read the first chapter (about the coffee shop) that is a good example. The buyCoffee function is not concerned with the transaction, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I provided an example of implementing a tail recursion manually. [Tail recursion - Scala (any language else)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896526/tail-recursion-scala-any-language-else/43897827#43897827)

It is an example of separation of algorithm description and evaluation.
`Recursive` trait describes only one iteration of some recursive algorithm.
Method `interpret` knows nothing about algorithm's logic and just runs it until it is finished.
For example you can introduce a delay between iteration or limit the number of iteration without changing the algorithm described in `Recursive`.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is in the phrase

> seperating program description from evaluation

An example is using a DSL represented by an ADT (that represents the grammar of your DSL) and an interpreter. Because other people are probably better than me in describing this in detail, I'll just link to an example here: http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/freemonad.html

That one uses free monads which are a somewhat hot topic currently but demonstrate very good what you're asking for in my opinion.